# check if one master order location tied to a local order in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two tables MASTER_ORDER and ORDER

```
MASTER_ORDER 
     MASTER_ORDER_ID not null
     LOCATION_ID not null

ORDER
     ORDER_ID not null
     LOCATION_ID not null
     MASTER_ORDER_ID default null
```

I am trying to check if all master orders are tied to the local (order) to the location id.

I tried something like this but this checks to see if there is at least one location tied to the local order (order table).  I need to check ALL locations but can't seem to figure out how to approach this issue

```
select  mo.master_order_id
from    master_order mo
where exists (
            select  1  
            from    order o
            where   o.location_id = mo.location_id
        )
```

Comment: rather than checking for All Locations, can you not check it as a negative condition. `Check Master orders, which do not have a location associated` you will only need to modify your query with `not exists`. will that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use all operator for checking ur condition something like below.

```
 select  mo.master_order_id
    from    master_order mo
    where   mo.location_id=All (
                select  o.location_id
                from   order o
            )
```